# ng-if inside ng-repeat is not filtering my array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Hy evryone, im trying to display tabs with a value inside my types array wchich has

```
[{"label":"wlan1","type":"wlan1"},
 {"label":"br-wlan","type":"br-wlan"},
 {"label":"tun_cas","type":"tun_cas"},
 {"label":"nfacct_bytes","type":"nfacct_bytes"},
 {"label":"wlan0","type":"wlan0"},
 {"label":"lte0","type":"lte0"},
 {"label":"nfacct_packets","type":"nfacct_packets"}]
```

In my view I dont want to display the types nfacct_bytes and nfacct_packets and for that I was doing:

```
<tab ng-if="type.label !== 'nfacct_bytes' || type.label !== 'nfacct_packets'" 
     ng-repeat="type in dataGraph.network.types" heading="{{type.label}}"
     select="changeSubTab(type.type)" disable="!tabClick" >
```

Solution:

```
<tab ng-if="type.label !== 'nfacct_bytes' && type.label !== 'nfacct_packets'" 
     ng-repeat="type in dataGraph.network.types" heading="{{type.label}}"
     select="changeSubTab(type.type)" disable="!tabClick" >
```

Comment: You edited the question to include the solution. This is not the way StackOverflow works. Mark the correct answer as accepted or provide your own answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check like this,

```
<tab ng-if="type.label !== 'nfacct_bytes' && type.label !== 'nfacct_packets' "> 
</tab>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('thecontroller',function($scope){
       $scope.dataGraph = {};
       $scope.dataGraph.network = {};
         $scope.dataGraph.network.types = [{"label":"wlan1","type":"wlan1"},{"label":"br-wlan","type":"br-wlan"},{"label":"tun_cas","type":"tun_cas"},{"label":"nfacct_bytes","type":"nfacct_bytes"},{"label":"wlan0","type":"wlan0"},{"label":"lte0","type":"lte0"},{"label":"nfacct_packets","type":"nfacct_packets"}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
          <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller='thecontroller'>
            <div  ng-repeat="type in dataGraph.network.types">
           <div ng-if="type.label !== 'nfacct_bytes' && type.label !== 'nfacct_packets' "> {{type.label}}
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I did 

<tab ng-if="type.label !== 'nfacct_bytes' || type.label !== 'nfacct_packets'" ng-repeat="type in dataGraph.network.types" heading="{{type.label}}" select="changeSubTab(type.type)" disable="!tabClick" >

and nothing happened, same problem... I get 7 tabs and i just want 5

Comment: @ricardol check the updated answer. you need to use &&

Answer (score 0):

Use **filter** function of angularJS. It Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

In filter the expression could be of string,object or function. Here I have used **expression as object**.

Let the controller be like this

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Values = 
     [{"label":"wlan1","type":"wlan1"},
     {"label":"br-wlan","type":"br-wlan"},
     {"label":"tun_cas","type":"tun_cas"},
     {"label":"nfacct_bytes","type":"nfacct_bytes"},
     {"label":"wlan0","type":"wlan0"},
     {"label":"lte0","type":"lte0"},
    {"label":"nfacct_packets","type":"nfacct_packets"}];
});
```

The required HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="value in Values |filter: {type: '!nfacct_bytes'}">
      {{value.label}}
  </div>
```

Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/IUvaZbzHdV0M1s9TRzAq?p=preview